# Всё равно ждёт. Асинхронный Python

Tags: python, async-await, асинхронность, asyncio

Разбираюсь с аsync в Python.
Вроде понимаю особенность работы асинхронности,но в есть программа, где имеется долгое ожидание, и почему то диспетчер ожидает, вместо того, чтобы проверить другой объект.

**Идея программы - доступность сетевых сервисов.

Используется библиотека pythonping для проверки доступности сервисов**

```
import asyncio
from pythonping import ping

async def ping_host(host):
    return ping(host).success()  # True or False при проверке  

async def check_host(host):
    check = await ping_host(host) 
    if check:
       print(host,'RUN')
    else:
       print(host, 'STOP')

tasks = [
    asyncio.ensure_feature(check_host('srv-01')),
    asyncio.ensure_feature(check_host('srv-02')),
    asyncio.ensure_feature(check_host('srv-03'))]

event_manager = asyncio.get_event_loop()
event_manager.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
event_manager.close()
```

Если указать просто check = await ping(host).success() то будет ошибка, поэтому      async def ping_host.

Итак, что не так?                                                                        В точке где check = await ping_host(host) если сервер недоступен, то ping очень долго ждёт(сек 4-5), поэтому здесь целесобразно переключиться к другой программе, пока ждём ответа, но почему то в моём коде это не работает.

В интеренете есть очень четкая блок-схема ([https://yandex.ru/images/search?from=tabbar&text=асинхронный%20python%203&pos=7&img_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.proglib.io%2Fwp-uploads%2F2018%2F07%2Fasync-programming-717x1024.jpg&rpt=simage](https://yandex.ru/images/search?from=tabbar&text=%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20python%203&pos=7&img_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.proglib.io%2Fwp-uploads%2F2018%2F07%2Fasync-programming-717x1024.jpg&rpt=simage)) исходя из которого в моей программе в блоке (I/O, sleep), event_manager должен был загрузить task 2.

Comment: Ну и что что вы написали `async` перед определением функции. Если в самой функции `ping_host` нет `await`, то она будет выполняться синхронно и вернёт управление только когда полностью завершится. Вам нужна либо асинхронная версия `ping`, если она где-то есть, и делать от неё `await`, либо нужно создавать поток для выполнения этого вызова, я не знаю, как это правильно делается в асинхронном питоне. В `C#` можно было бы `Task` создать.

Comment: Попробуйте советы из этого вопроса: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241221/how-can-i-wrap-a-synchronous-function-in-an-async-coroutine

Comment: А вот асинхронный пинг готовый, лучше его возьмите https://github.com/stellarbit/aioping

Comment: спасибо! теперь понятно!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async def ping_host(host):
    return ping(host).success()  # True or False при проверке
```

Модификатор `async` не превращает синхронную функцию автоматически в асинхронную. Да, вы теперь можете сделать такой функции `await`, но она не вернёт управление в момент ожидания, поскольку в самой этой функции нет ни одной конструкции `await`, при выполнении которой управление может возвращаться. Эта функция выполнится целиком и только тогда вернёт управление.

Правильнее всего в такой ситуации взять готовый асинхронный `ping`, например [aioping](https://github.com/stellarbit/aioping). Пример использования из документации. Обратите внимание на `await` внутри функции `do_ping`:

```
import asyncio
import aioping

async def do_ping(host):
    try:
        delay = await aioping.ping(host) * 1000
        print("Ping response in %s ms" % delay)

    except TimeoutError:
        print("Timed out")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(do_ping("google.com"))
```

Можно при желании и самому превратить синхронную функцию в асинхронную, примеры можно найти [здесь.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241221/how-can-i-wrap-a-synchronous-function-in-an-async-coroutine) Но обычно лучше всё-таки использовать библиотеку, которая "из коробки" поддерживает асинхронные вызовы.

Comment: Получается что не каждый раз можно применить асинхронность когда идёт ожидание? 
А как тогда понять что мой pythonping просто синхронный?

Comment: @legion088 фактически все функции, работающие без await - синхронные.

Comment: @legion088 Ну раз там не написано что он асинхронный и в документации нет примеров вызова его методов через await или через `asyncio` какое-нибудь, значит он синхронный. Чтобы применить ожидание через `await` функция должна его поддерживать. И просто написать `async` перед функцией для этого, повторюсь, недостаточно.

Comment: Всё понятно! Я думал так лего и просто-сделал асинхронную функцию, и наслаждаешься переключением. Оказывается ещё всё зависит от применяемых библиотек. 
Спасибо!